# How do I create a list inside python dictionary having key and key variable?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an empty dictionary. I add key and key variable to that dictionary. How do I create an empty list having key and key variable?

```
  result = {}
  result['key'] = 20
  print(result)=  {'key': 20}

  result['key'] = []
  result2 = {}
  result['key'].append(result2)






Expected result : {'key':20 : [{'7219': '0.49954929481682875'}, {'1416': '0.48741579334133667'}
```

But it comes like,

```
{'key': [{'7219': '0.49954929481682875'}, {'1416': '0.48741579334133667'}]
```

Comment: Your expected result is invalid Python. You want to have a dictionary where a key maps to an integer plus a list? Then use a tuple.

Comment: where are the numbers coming from?

Comment: I do an operation and generate scores which gets inside result2. I am trying to append those values to empty list.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need.

```
result = {}
result['key'] = {20: []}
print(result) # --> {'key': {20: []}}

result2 = {}
result['key'][20].append(result2)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, you do not necessarily want to save the value "20" with the key "key", but rather use "20" as the key. In order to achieve that, your code should look like the following (careful, this basically spells out every step):

```
# save an empty list using the key int(20)

# define the key and an empty dictionary
my_key = 20
result = {}
# use the key variable as key for the dictionary and create an empty list there
result[my_key] = []

# now add the other result dictionary to this list
result2 = {
    #... some entries
}
result[my_key].append(result2)
# ... some more code
```

This finally results in a dictionary in this form:

```
{20 : [{'7219': '0.49954929481682875'}, {'1416': '0.48741579334133667'}]}
```

However, this is only my interpretation of your issue. If I got something wrong, just ping me up.

Comment: I want to add key to the value 20. Because the next step is to see if that key is found in mongodb. When I have an ID it'll be easy to fetch.